# Swift delete file (Move to Bin) with (Put Back) functionality using FileManager.default.trashItem

Tags: swift, macos

Using the following code I am able to delete a file which is moved to trash, but there is no "Put Back" functionality. When I right click the file in trash only delete immediately option is available.

```
let srcURL = URL(fileURLWithPath:filename!)
var trashedPath: NSURL!

try! FileManager.default.trashItem(at: srcURL, resultingItemURL: &trashedPath)
```

My program is a Finder Quick Action Service written in Swift 5.4, where I am passing one or more filenames with path of image files like `.heic`, `.png`, `.tiff`, and converting it to `jpg`. I then want to delete the source file and move them to trash. As the files can be from different directories I want to provide the facility where the user can restore the deleted source file to its proper place.

What should be done to get "Put Back" option?

Comment: You need to edit the .DS_Store file in the trash folder. See [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52357/how-to-determine-original-location-of-file-that-is-currently-in-the-trash). From the looks of it, it's not easy.

Comment: Another idea I thought of is to run some apple script (`NSAppscript`) that `tell application "Finder"` to `move file to trash`, which works, but I'm not sure if that is appropriate for your application. I don't know what a "Finder Quick Action Service" is.

Comment: @Sweeper To mess with undocumented .DS_Store is beyond me and I am also looking at a way to invoke the finder app to delete the file but it would be much slower. There is also NSWorkspaceRecycleOperation method which I have to try to see its behaviour. By the way a Finder Quick Action is a right click menu item for selected file/s, so in my case you select bunch of non .jpg image files right click and select ToJpg under Quick Action menu and it will convert all those file to jpegs.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my research suggest that the "Put Back" functionality is only available thru Finder. I came across Trash - [Trash by ali-rantakari on github](https://github.com/ali-rantakari/trash)
Now I have to implement a way to run this command in swift, which is as follows.

```
@discardableResult
func shell(_ args: String...) -> Int32 {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
    task.arguments = args
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return task.terminationStatus
}

shell("trash","-F", "\(filename!)")
```

Comment: I have used your function and when I run my program from terminal (it's a command line program like ls) it works but if I call that command from other program it will not work and the trash command gives an error -1701. By trying out many things and researching on internet I am assuming that it has to do with apple sandboxing. It will not allow a process call to external program. Only thing left to try is calling applscript from swift to do something like osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\" to delete POSIX file \"$file\"" >/dev/null